# scroll to id element when using "?" in url, vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, anchor-scroll

I have this url http://localhost:8080/?london and it needs to load to the id of london in `<section id="london">.`- which is on the page.
I cannot use http://localhost:8080/#london, even though that will work!

To make things more complicated I am using a vue framework and they want the code inside master-origin/src/assets/js/mixins/Anchor.js - therefore I can't install jquery, has to be vanilla js.

I have tried

```
var el = [];
el = window.location.href.split("/?")[1];
console.log("el: " + el);
el.scrollIntoView();
```

Which grabs the value after the /?, but I when I tried to scrollIntoView, I get this message in the console

> TypeError: el.scrollIntoView is not a function
>       at VM10022 IE work:4

Why? I am following w3 schools guide https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You try to call `.scrollIntoView()` on a string.

Try this: `document.getElementById(el).scrollIntoView();`

Answer (score 9):

Works great for me

```
const el = document.getElementById('item');
      el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  window.scrollTo({
        top: document.getElementById("allCars").offsetTop,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
```